# How do I give an effect to all players that are not in the radius of 4 around my villager?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have the command:

```
execute @e[type=Villager] ~ ~ ~ effect @a[r=!4] 19 5 2
```

It should give poison to all players that are not in the radius of 4 blocks around my villager, but it does not work.

Is there an issue with `[r=!4]`?

Comment: Instead of using `@a[r=!4]`, that apparently does not work because you can't negate *4* (it will generate some negative number, probably around -2^31), use `@a[rm=5]`. `rm` means *minimum radius*, so that everyone who is 5 or more (more than 4) blocks away from your villager gets affected by the command.

Comment: @GiantTree, That's correct! You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `@a[r=!4]` with `@a[rm=5]`. The `rm` stands for **minimum radius**, so everyone with a minimum radius of 5 will be affected, but everyone with a radius that is less than 5 will not be affected. Your final command should then be:

```
execute @e[type=Villager] ~ ~ ~ effect @a[rm=5] 19 5 2
```

**EDIT:** I saw afterwards that @GiantTree also said this, sorry if it is seen as a copy, but I didn't see it there.